# PHP : mysql result have space

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I've tried to show MYSQL result inside JQUERY AUTOCOMPLETE,the result is show space before result value.And then I try to check with firebug show :

```
1        //show space
2 046A
3
```

this my php script:

```
$sql="SELECT lotno FROM dataserial 
      WHERE model='".$Mod."' AND startserial <= '".$Ser."' 
      AND endserial >= '".$Ser."'";
$res=mysqli_query($sql) or die(_ERROR26.": ".mysqli_error());
```

this my ajax :

```
....
success: function(res){
      $('#lotprod').attr("value",res);
     }
....
```

$res result:

```
Resource id #6
```

Comment: what's the output that query is showing?

Comment: Please don't use the _deprecated_ `mysql_*` extension anymore. _Deprecated_ means it's no longer supported, and it will be removed some time in the future. Switch to its newer alternatives: either `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: did you want echo of sql?

Comment: $res is either false or an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably some whitespace somewhere in your code before your actual output happens. The whitespace may be in the same file you're outputting from or in a file you have included somewhere.

You should find the whitespace and remove it, or as a quick fix. You can do something like:

```
ob_clean();
echo 'your output';
```

That will clear any whitespace before the [ob_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) call.

Comment: great Hein, this cleaning help me.